# Writing an image to a text/raw file in C

Tags: c, image-processing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char **T;
    int H[256];
    int I[256][256];
    int i,j,a,aux[256];
    FILE *fp=fopen("Collines400300.ima","rb");
    FILE *fp1=fopen("image4.raw","wb");
    int height = 300;
    int width = 400;

    T=(unsigned char**)malloc(height*sizeof(unsigned char*));
    for(i=0;i<height;i++)
    {
    if (feof(fp))
    {
       //handle error... could just malloc and memset to zero's
       break;
    }
    T[i]=(unsigned char*)malloc(width*sizeof(unsigned char*));
    fread(T[i],1,400,fp);
    }
    for(i=0;i<256;i++)
    H[i]=0;

    //filling up the histogram
    for(i=0;i<300;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<400;j++)
        H[T[i][j]]++;
    }
    //printing out the values of each gray scale value in the histogram
    for(i=0;i<256;i++)
    printf("%d  ",H[i]);

    //converting the values from a scale of 3000 to a scaale of 256 to fit in our new image
    for(i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        a=(H[i]+6)/12;
        aux[i]=a;
    }
    //initialising the 2D image to white
    for(i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<256;j++)
        I[i][j]=255;
    }
    //the loop to make the graph for my histogram. This is where the problem is.
    for(i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        for(j=254;j>254-aux[i];j--)
        {
            I[j][i]=0;
            fwrite(I[i],1,aux[i],fp1);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);



    return 0;


}
```

Given an image I am supposed to make a histogram of the image, which I did. Then make a graph of the histogram in a 2D image and write it to a file. I am not getting the graph I want, but a very blurry image with no sense to it. Thank you for any help beforehand.

Comment: If your input image is 400x300, why do you think the histogram will need scaling from 3,000 to 256? Surely you need to find the maximum value in the histogram by looping through it, and then multiply all values in your histogram by 255/max?

Answer (score 0):

`I[j][i]=0; fwrite(I[i],1,aux[i],fp1);` Did you mean to write the <s>column</s> row to file here? It doesn't work that way. You are modifying an element in <s>(column number `i`)</s> row number `j` in memory and then writing row number `i` to file.

Comment: I want to write the image line for line in my file. That is why I did that.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write a row `fwrite(I[j], ...`. I doubt you meant to write a column `for(j1=0;j1<aux1;j1++){fwrite(I[j1][i], 1, 1, ...` and I seriously doubt you meant to write the wrong row `fwrite(I[i], ...`.

Comment: Yea but this here didn't work either. I am still not able to get the graph I want.

Comment: Oh, isn't it making a white line straight down the right-hand edge of a black graph? Isn't that what you wanted? I thought you might have decided to graph a constant function for now, on purpose, in order to debug your program.

Comment: No, I want to graph the function of my histogram right away. But it is not working for some reason.